# Non measurable vector subspace of a Banach space

Tags: measure-theory, vector-spaces, operator-theory, banach-spaces

My question is the following:

Let $(E,\Vert\cdot\Vert_E)$ be a real Banach space, $\mathcal{B}(E)$ its Borel sigma algebra (i.e. the sigma algebra containing all open balls). Is it possible for a vector subspace $V$ of $E$ to be non-measurable? In particular, is it possible in the case $E$ is separable?

The question arises from this particular case: let $A:D(A)\to F$ be a closed operator, where $(F,\Vert\cdot\Vert_F)$ is another Banach space and $D(A)$ is a vector subspace of $E$. Let $X$ be an $E$-valued random variable (from a standard probability space) such that $X$ belongs to $D(A)$ $\mathbb{P}$-almost surely. Is it true that $AX$ is an $F$-valued random variable? In the case I impose $D(A)$ to be measurable, I can prove it without difficulties. So the (more specific than the one above) question is: does a closed operator $A$ defined on a non measurable domain $D(A)$ exist?

In the case the space $F$ is reflexive, I'm able to show that $D(A)$ must be measurable by expressing it as a countable union of closed sets, but I have no idea how to approach the problem without any assumption on $F$.

UPDATE

I'm trying to construct a counterxample using the following space:

$$E=\bigg\{ f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R} \text{ such that } \sum_{x\in [0,1]} f(x)^2<\infty\bigg\}$$

where the sum (of nonnegative elements) over a non countable set in defined in the following way:

$$\sum_{x\in [0,1]} a_x = \sup\bigg\{ \sum_{i\in I} a_i : I\subset [0,1] \text{ finite} \bigg\}$$

In the case the elements can have both positive and negative sign but $\sum_{x\in [01]}\vert a_x\vert <\infty$, then the sum $\sum_{x\in [0,1]} a_x$ is defined by taking positive and negative parts respectively.

This definition of sum has the nice property that if $\sum_{x\in [0,1]} \vert a_x\vert<\infty$, then there can be at most a countable amount of points $x$ such that $a_x\neq0$. Now $E$ is a vector space that can be normed with
$$ \Vert f\Vert_E = \sqrt{\sum_{x\in [0,1]} f(x)^2}$$
which is induced by the scalar product
$$\langle f,g\rangle = \sum_{x\in [0,1]} f(x)g(x)$$
It can be shown that $E$ is a Banach (and therefore Hilbert) space; it is not separable, since the family $\{e_x : x\in [0,1]\}$ ($e_x$ denotes the function that sents $x$ to $1$ and everything else to $0$) is an uncountable, $1$-separated family. Moreover $\{e_x : x\in [0,1]\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $E$ (in the sense that is a family of orthonormal elements such that any $f\in E$ can be arbitrarily approximated by finite linear combinations of it). I think $E$ is a good place where to search for a counterexample since it's nice enough to work with it but at the same time a bit strange (it contains infinite copies of the $l^2$ space).

In order to show that a subspace is not measurable, I should show that it is the image through a measurable map of a non measurable set from another measurable space. My candidate for the non measurable subspace was something like
$$ V = span\{ e_x : x\in A\}$$
where $A$ is a Vitali set (or any other non measurable subset of [0,1]). So what I'd like is a measurable map $T:(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))\to (E,\mathcal{B}(E))$ (actually $T$ does not need to start from $\mathbb{R}$ but I guess that's the space one would work with) such that the image of a non measurable subset through $T$ is $V$.

However I haven't find anything so far. Any ideas? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you assume that $X$ belongs to $D(A)$ almost surely, dont you assume that $D(A)$ is measurable already?

Comment: I don’t think so. That condition tells me that $X^{-1}(D(A))$ is measurable with measure 0. A priori the preimage of a non measurable set could still be measurable. Anyway it doesn’t change the nature of the question: is the condition $D(A)$ measurable necessary to formulate the problem/ solve it? I.e. there are actually examples of closed operators such that $D(A)$ is not measurable?

Comment: It helps here to distinguish between "measurable" and "Borel".  Many people use "measurable" to mean "measurable with respect to the completion of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra by $\mathbb{P}$".

Comment: Hi Lucio. I was trying to work through your original problem. Do you remember how to show that AX is an F-valued r.v. if D(A) is measurable? I've been trying to use the graph norm but I get stuck because I'm not seeing how X being B(E) measurable implies X is D(A) measurable (with graph norm inducing a different topology). Thanks!

Comment: @abe.nong Sorry, it was quite a long ago, I don't remember. Probably I was reasoning like you, once you show that $X$ is $D(A)$ measurable, since $A:D(A)\to F$ is continuous, the conclusion follows. But right now I don't remember how to show that the injection $J:E\to D(A)$ given by $J(x)=x$ if $x\in D(A)$, $J(x)=0$ otherwise, is measurable; maybe at the time I overlooked some details. I think in the case both spaces are separable, the tools from descriptive set theory from Nate's answer should also set this case.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have some more structure, like the spaces being weakly compact, I think a combination of weak compactness and Mazur lemma could be enough to show that sets like $\{x\in E: \Vert x-y\Vert_{D(A)}\leq R\}$ are closed in $E$. But again, I don't remember the details, might be saying silly stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very brief answers (will expand if I have time):

1. Yes, $V$ can be non-Borel.  The kernel of a discontinuous linear functional has this property.  See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41314/non-borel-subspace-of-banach-space
2. If $E$ and $F$ are both separable, the domain of a closed operator is necessarily Borel.   See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219391/existence-of-closed-operators-with-arbitrary-dense-domain-of-a-given-banach-spac for an argument from some standard facts in descriptive set theory.  There may be an elementary proof also.  I am not sure what happens if they are not both separable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I’d really appreciate if you could further extend it! I searched quickly on the web, is the fact from descriptive set theory you are quoting called Souslin theorem? Also a clarification on part 2: are we assuming also F to be separable in order for $E\times F$ to be polish? Or this is not necessary, like maybe the closure of the image of A inherits separability from the separability of E?

Comment: @Lucio: Added a reference (an MO answer of mine - I knew this sounded familiar).  You're right that this argument does need $F$ to be separable also, though perhaps that can be avoided somehow.